# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

Tags: duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I migrated source code from Eclipse to Android studio, when I build the project in android studio, I got the following failure.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile (project(':facebook')){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
    compile project(':libraryBasePera')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

I tried many ways (exclude module support-v4, deleted support-v4 jar, clean, rebuild project...) but I am still stuck here. Can any one help me to figure out the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check lib folder. I had same error because I have added **support-v4 jar** in my lib folder by mistake.